# Mouse position taking into account Windows 10 global scaling

Tags: javascript, windows, mouse

In my webpage a make use of `mousemove` event and its `clientX` and `clientY` properties.
It works as intended, and I am normalizing the coordinates this way:

```
    MousePos.x = ((event.clientX- Renderer.domElement.offsetLeft) / Renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
    MousePos.y = -((event.clientY - Renderer.domElement.offsetTop) / Renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;
```

It works as intended and now x and y are in a range from -1 to 1 instead of 0 to width/height.

The issue arises when the machine has a global scaling; Windows 10 has such option. Lets say that my screen is 1920 pixels wide, and scaling is set to 100% (no global scaling), then `event.clientX` maximum value will be 1920. If the scaling is some other value it wont be the width of the screen at its maximum value, which won't give me 1 value and the normalized mouse position will be wrong.

So my question is: how to take into account the windows 10 global scaling?

If I could read this value I could correct my mouse position this way:

```
    let scale = 1.25;
MousePos.x = ((event.clientX * scale - Renderer.domElement.offsetLeft) / Renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
MousePos.y = -((event.clientY * scale - Renderer.domElement.offsetTop) / Renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;
```

But I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect scale settings (dpi) with JavaScript or CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791052/detect-scale-settings-dpi-with-javascript-or-css)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `domElement` has another property: `clientWidth` (or height) which should be used to normalize.

The following works as intended:

```
    MousePos.x = ((event.clientX - Renderer.domElement.offsetLeft) / Renderer.domElement.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
MousePos.y = -((event.clientY - Renderer.domElement.offsetTop) / Renderer.domElement.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
```