# I have issue to make Dynamic Position inputs at JavaScript Component?

Tags: javascript, css

The idea behind Component to when Click put inputs at Image ,for example put input as measures on image , but i want these inputs to be same point whatever large or small screen , i tried but its fixed Top & Left at All Screen any ideas i may forget Something

```
const image = document.getElementById("image");
const inputContainer = document.getElementById("input-container");
const tableBody = document.getElementById("table-body");

let currentInput = null;


function addInput(event) {
     const newInput = document.createElement("input");
     newInput.type = "text";
     newInput.classList.add('input-img');
     newInput.classList.add("form-control");

     const rect = image.getBoundingClientRect();
     const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
     const y = event.clientY - rect.top;

     newInput.style.position = "absolute";
     newInput.style.width = `${newInput.offsetWidth + 50}px`;
     newInput.style.left = `${x}px`;
     newInput.style.top = `${y}px`;
     
     

     // =============== Draggable
     let isDragging = false;
     let startX;
     let startY;

     newInput.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
          isDragging = true;
          startX = event.clientX - newInput.offsetLeft;
          startY = event.clientY - newInput.offsetTop;
     });

     newInput.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
          if (isDragging) {
               newInput.style.left = `${event.clientX - startX}px`;
               newInput.style.top = `${event.clientY - startY}px`;
          }
     });

     newInput.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
          isDragging = false;
     });

   
     currentInput = newInput;
     inputContainer.appendChild(newInput);
}


function addValue() {
     if (!currentInput) {
          return;
     }

     const value = currentInput.value;
     if (value === "") {
          return;
     }

     const inputName = document.createElement("input");
     inputName.type = "text";
     inputName.value = `Input ${tableBody.childElementCount + 1}`;

     const row = document.createElement("tr");
     const nameCell = document.createElement("td");
     const valueCell = document.createElement("td");

     nameCell.appendChild(inputName);
     row.appendChild(nameCell);





     const valueSpan = document.createElement("span");
     valueSpan.textContent = value;
     valueSpan.classList.add("value-text");
     valueCell.appendChild(valueSpan);



     row.appendChild(valueCell);

     tableBody.appendChild(row);

     //   currentInput.remove();
     //   currentInput = null;
     currentInput.style.border = "none"
     currentInput.style.background = "none"

}

image.addEventListener("dblclick", addInput);
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
     if (event.key === "Enter") {
          addValue();
     }
});
```

for CSS image-container take position relative which hold image and inputs Wrapper

```
    <div class="mx-4 mt-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4">
          <div class="image-container d-flex flex-col justify-content-center align-items-center">
               <img src="img.png" alt="your-image-description" id="image">
               <div class="input-container" id="input-container">
                    <!-- Input field will be added dynamically here -->
               </div>
          </div>

          <table class="table table-striped">
               <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th>Input</th>
                         <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody id="table-body"></tbody>
          </table>

     </div>
```

i tried to put offset and determine top and left

```
  const left = event.clientX - containerRect.left;
     const top = event.clientY - containerRect.top;
```

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59809239/mouse-position-taking-into-account-windows-10-global-scaling